# SCORM 2004 Sequencing... what am i doing wrong (Passed automatically in LMS)

Tags: sequence, scorm

See my manifest below.

I believe it's correct but still enter to the course in LMS and the items mod01, mod02 and mod03 show "passed" and the sequency show totally open.

```
<?xml version = "1.0" standalone = "yes"?>
<manifest identifier="com.scorm.golfsamples.contentpackaging.multioscosinglefile.20043rd" version="1"
          ...


 <metadata>
  <schema>ADL SCORM</schema>
  <schemaversion>2004 3rd Edition</schemaversion>
 </metadata>

 <organizations default="GESTAO_ESTRATEGICA">
  <organization identifier="GESTAO_ESTRATEGICA">
   <title>GESTÃO ESTRATÉGICA TESTANDO SESSÃO</title>




   <!-- DISCIPLINA 01 -->

     <item identifier="mod01">
      <title>HABILIDADES GERENCIAIS ESTRATÉGICAS</title>
      <!-- TRABALHA SEQUENCIA -->

       <imsss:sequencing IDRef="sequencia_principal">        

        <imsss:objectives>
        <!--
        Each SCO has a global objective to that can be read by other SCOs to see if it is completed.
        This global will be satisfied when the activity is satisfied since it is associated with the
        primary objective
        -->
         <imsss:primaryObjective objectiveID="mod__01">
          <imsss:mapInfo targetObjectiveID = "mod_01_OK" readSatisfiedStatus = "true" writeSatisfiedStatus = "true"/>
         </imsss:primaryObjective>
        </imsss:objectives>
        <imsss:deliveryControls completionSetByContent="true" objectiveSetByContent="true"/>
       </imsss:sequencing>

       <item identifier="capam1" identifierref="capam1">
        <title>Sobre o Módulo</title>
       </item>
       <item identifier="un0001" identifierref="un0001">
        <title>Cenário Mercardológico</title>
       </item>
       <item identifier="un0002" identifierref="un0002">
        <title>Case Cirque Du Soleil</title>
       </item>
       <item identifier="un0003" identifierref="un0003">
        <title>Fundamentos da Administração</title>
       </item>
       <item identifier="un0004" identifierref="un0004">
        <title>Planejamento Estratégico</title>
       </item>
       <item identifier="aval01" isvisible="true" identifierref="aval01_RES">
        <title>Avaliação do Módulo</title>
        <imsss:sequencing>
         <imsss:objectives>
          <imsss:primaryObjective objectiveID="PRIMARYOBJ" satisfiedByMeasure="true">
          <imsss:deliveryControls completionSetByContent="true" objectiveSetByContent="true"/>
           <imsss:minNormalizedMeasure>0.6</imsss:minNormalizedMeasure>
          </imsss:primaryObjective>
         </imsss:objectives>
         <imsss:deliveryControls completionSetByContent="true" objectiveSetByContent="true"/>
        </imsss:sequencing>
       </item>
     </item>

   <!-- DISCIPLINA 02 -->

     <item identifier="mod02">
      <title>MARKETING: UM DIFERENCIAL COMPETITIVO</title>

       <!-- TRABALHA SEQUENCIA -->

       <imsss:sequencing IDRef="sequencia_principal">
        <imsss:sequencingRules>
         <imsss:preConditionRule>
          <!--  
            If the previous SCO is not satisfied or the status is unknown, disable this SCO.
            Notice that the "not" operator isn't a logical NOT in which all other conditions evaluate
            to true. Instead it indicates that "not satisfied" is the only condition that evaluates to true.
          -->
          <imsss:ruleConditions conditionCombination="any">
           <imsss:ruleCondition referencedObjective="previous_sco_satisfied" operator="not" condition="satisfied"/>
           <imsss:ruleCondition referencedObjective="previous_sco_satisfied" operator="not" condition="objectiveStatusKnown"/>
          </imsss:ruleConditions>

          <!--  'Disabled' will cause the SCO to be visible in the course tree, but not accessible via choice or flow.  -->

          <imsss:ruleAction action="hiddenFromChoice"/>
         </imsss:preConditionRule>
        </imsss:sequencingRules>

        <imsss:objectives>
         <imsss:primaryObjective objectiveID="mod__02">
          <imsss:mapInfo targetObjectiveID = "mod_02_OK" readSatisfiedStatus = "true" writeSatisfiedStatus = "true"/>
         </imsss:primaryObjective>

         <!--
          Set up another objective to read the status of this activity's prerequisite. We can then use this objective in
          our sequencing rules to disable this activity.
         -->
         <imsss:objective objectiveID="previous_sco_satisfied">
          <imsss:mapInfo targetObjectiveID="mod_01_OK" readSatisfiedStatus="true" writeSatisfiedStatus="false"/>
         </imsss:objective>
        </imsss:objectives>
        <imsss:deliveryControls completionSetByContent="true" objectiveSetByContent="true"/>
       </imsss:sequencing>

      <item identifier="capam2" identifierref="capam2">
       <title>Sobre o Módulo</title>
      </item>
      <item identifier="un0006" identifierref="un0006">
       <title>A Importância do Marketing para Micro, Pequenas e Médias Empresas</title>
      </item>
      <item identifier="un0007" identifierref="un0007">
       <title>O Ambiente de Marketing</title>
      </item>
      <item identifier="un0008" identifierref="un0008">
       <title>Comportamento do Consumidor</title>
      </item>
      <item identifier="un0009" identifierref="un0009">
       <title>O Composto Mercadológico</title>
      </item>
      <item identifier="un0010" identifierref="un0010">
       <title>Estratégias de Marketing e Relacionamento</title>
      </item>
      <item identifier="un0011" isvisible="true" identifierref="un0011_RES">
       <title>Avaliação de Módulo</title>
       <imsss:sequencing>
        <imsss:objectives>
         <imsss:primaryObjective objectiveID="PRIMARYOBJ" satisfiedByMeasure="true">
          <imsss:minNormalizedMeasure>0.6</imsss:minNormalizedMeasure>
         </imsss:primaryObjective>
        </imsss:objectives>
        <imsss:deliveryControls completionSetByContent="true" objectiveSetByContent="true"/>
       </imsss:sequencing>
      </item>
     </item>

   <!-- DISCIPLINA 03 -->
     <item identifier="mod03">
      <title>EMPREENDEDORISMO: CRIAÇÃO E GESTÃO DE NOVOS NEGÓCIOS</title>

       <!-- TRABALHA SEQUENCIA -->

       <imsss:sequencing IDRef="sequencia_principal">
        <imsss:sequencingRules>
         <imsss:preConditionRule>
          <!--  
            If the previous SCO is not satisfied or the status is unknown, disable this SCO.
            Notice that the "not" operator isn't a logical NOT in which all other conditions evaluate
            to true. Instead it indicates that "not satisfied" is the only condition that evaluates to true.
          -->
          <imsss:ruleConditions conditionCombination="any">
           <imsss:ruleCondition referencedObjective="previous_sco_satisfied" operator="not" condition="satisfied"/>
           <imsss:ruleCondition referencedObjective="previous_sco_satisfied" operator="not" condition="objectiveStatusKnown"/>
          </imsss:ruleConditions> 

          <!--  'Disabled' will cause the SCO to be visible in the course tree, but not accessible via choice or flow.  -->

          <imsss:ruleAction action="hiddenFromChoice"/>
         </imsss:preConditionRule>
        </imsss:sequencingRules>

        <imsss:objectives>
         <imsss:primaryObjective objectiveID="mod__03">
          <imsss:mapInfo targetObjectiveID = "mod_03_OK" readSatisfiedStatus = "true" writeSatisfiedStatus = "true"/>
         </imsss:primaryObjective>

         <!--
          Set up another objective to read the status of this activity's prerequisite. We can then use this objective in
          our sequencing rules to disable this activity.
         -->

         <imsss:objective objectiveID="previous_sco_satisfied">
          <imsss:mapInfo targetObjectiveID="mod_02_OK" readSatisfiedStatus="true" writeSatisfiedStatus="false"/>
         </imsss:objective>
        </imsss:objectives>
        <imsss:deliveryControls completionSetByContent="true" objectiveSetByContent="true"/>
       </imsss:sequencing>

      <item identifier="capam3" identifierref="capam3">
       <title>Sobre o Módulo</title>
      </item>
      <item identifier="un0012" identifierref="un0012">
       <title>Introdução ao Empreendedorismo</title>
      </item>
      <item identifier="un0013" identifierref="un0013">
       <title>O Empreendedor e o Mercado</title>
      </item>

      <item identifier="un0014" isvisible="true" identifierref="un0014_RES">
       <title>Avaliação de Módulo</title>
       <imsss:sequencing>
        <imsss:objectives>
         <imsss:primaryObjective objectiveID="PRIMARYOBJ" satisfiedByMeasure="true">
          <imsss:minNormalizedMeasure>0.6</imsss:minNormalizedMeasure>
         </imsss:primaryObjective>
        </imsss:objectives>
        <imsss:deliveryControls completionSetByContent="true" objectiveSetByContent="true"/>
       </imsss:sequencing>
      </item>
     </item>


  </organization>
 </organizations>



 <resources>
  <!-- DISCIPLINA 01 -->

   <resource identifier="capam1" href="Pacote05_M1_HabGerenEstrat/capa_hge.html" adlcp:scormType="sco" type="webcontent">
     <file href="Pacote05_M1_HabGerenEstrat/capa_hge.html" />
     <dependency identifierref="assets" />
   </resource>
   <resource identifier="un0001" href="Pacote05_M1_HabGerenEstrat/Unid_I/unidade.html" adlcp:scormType="sco" type="webcontent">
     <file href="Pacote05_M1_HabGerenEstrat/Unid_I/unidade.html" />
     <dependency identifierref="assets" />
   </resource>
   <resource identifier="un0002" href="Pacote05_M1_HabGerenEstrat/Unid_II/unidade.html" adlcp:scormType="sco" type="webcontent">
     <file href="Pacote05_M1_HabGerenEstrat/Unid_II/unidade.html" />
     <dependency identifierref="assets" />
   </resource>
   <resource identifier="un0003" href="Pacote05_M1_HabGerenEstrat/Unid_III/unidade.html" adlcp:scormType="sco" type="webcontent">
     <file href="Pacote05_M1_HabGerenEstrat/Unid_III/unidade.html" />
     <dependency identifierref="assets" />
   </resource>
   <resource identifier="un0004" href="Pacote05_M1_HabGerenEstrat/Unid_IV/unidade.html" adlcp:scormType="sco" type="webcontent">
     <file href="Pacote05_M1_HabGerenEstrat/Unid_IV/unidade.html" />
     <dependency identifierref="assets" />
   </resource>


   <resource identifier="aval01_RES" href="Pacote05_M1_HabGerenEstrat/Unid_V_Avaliacao/aval.html" adlcp:scormType="sco" type="webcontent">
     <file href="Pacote05_M1_HabGerenEstrat/Unid_V_Avaliacao/aval.html"></file>
     <file href="Pacote05_M1_HabGerenEstrat/Unid_V_Avaliacao/aval.swf"></file>
     <file href="Pacote05_M1_HabGerenEstrat/Unid_V_Avaliacao/APIWrapper.js"></file>
     <file href="Pacote05_M1_HabGerenEstrat/Unid_V_Avaliacao/ieupdate.js"></file>
   </resource>

  <!-- DISCIPLINA 02 -->

   <resource identifier="capam2" href="Pacote06_M1_MktDiferenCompet/capa_mkt.html" adlcp:scormType="sco" type="webcontent">
     <file href="Pacote06_M1_MktDiferenCompet/capa_mkt.html" />
     <dependency identifierref="assets" />
   </resource>
   <resource identifier="un0006" href="Pacote06_M1_MktDiferenCompet/Unid_I/unidade.html" adlcp:scormType="sco" type="webcontent">
     <file href="Pacote06_M1_MktDiferenCompet/Unid_I/unidade.html" />
     <dependency identifierref="assets" />
   </resource>
   <resource identifier="un0007" href="Pacote06_M1_MktDiferenCompet/Unid_II/unidade.html" adlcp:scormType="sco" type="webcontent">
     <file href="Pacote06_M1_MktDiferenCompet/Unid_II/unidade.html" />
     <dependency identifierref="assets" />
   </resource>
   <resource identifier="un0008" href="Pacote06_M1_MktDiferenCompet/Unid_III/unidade.html" adlcp:scormType="sco" type="webcontent">
     <file href="Pacote06_M1_MktDiferenCompet/Unid_III/unidade.html" />
     <dependency identifierref="assets" />
   </resource>
   <resource identifier="un0009" href="Pacote06_M1_MktDiferenCompet/Unid_IV/unidade.html" adlcp:scormType="sco" type="webcontent">
     <file href="Pacote06_M1_MktDiferenCompet/Unid_IV/unidade.html" />
     <dependency identifierref="assets" />
   </resource>
   <resource identifier="un0010" href="Pacote06_M1_MktDiferenCompet/Unid_V/unidade.html" adlcp:scormType="sco" type="webcontent">
     <file href="Pacote06_M1_MktDiferenCompet/Unid_V/unidade.html" />
     <dependency identifierref="assets" />
   </resource>


   <resource identifier="un0011_RES" href="Pacote06_M1_MktDiferenCompet/Unid_VI_Avaliacao/aval.html" adlcp:scormType="sco" type="webcontent">
     <file href="Pacote06_M1_MktDiferenCompet/Unid_VI_Avaliacao/aval.html"></file>
     <file href="Pacote06_M1_MktDiferenCompet/Unid_VI_Avaliacao/aval.swf"></file>
     <file href="Pacote06_M1_MktDiferenCompet/Unid_VI_Avaliacao/APIWrapper.js"></file>
     <file href="Pacote06_M1_MktDiferenCompet/Unid_VI_Avaliacao/ieupdate.js"></file>
   </resource>


   <!-- DISCIPLINA 03 -->

   <resource identifier="capam3" href="Pacote07_M1_Empreed/capa_emp.html" adlcp:scormType="sco" type="webcontent">
     <file href="Pacote07_M1_Empreed/capa_emp.html" />
     <dependency identifierref="assets" />
   </resource>
   <resource identifier="un0012" href="Pacote07_M1_Empreed/Unid_I/unidade.html" adlcp:scormType="sco" type="webcontent">
     <file href="Pacote07_M1_Empreed/Unid_I/unidade.html" />
     <dependency identifierref="assets" />
   </resource>
   <resource identifier="un0013" href="Pacote07_M1_Empreed/Unid_II/unidade.html" adlcp:scormType="sco" type="webcontent">
     <file href="Pacote07_M1_Empreed/Unid_II/unidade.html" />
     <dependency identifierref="assets" />
   </resource>



  <resource identifier="un0014_RES" href="Pacote07_M1_Empreed/Unid_III_Avaliacao/aval.html" adlcp:scormType="sco" type="webcontent">
     <file href="Pacote07_M1_Empreed/Unid_III_Avaliacao/aval.html"></file>
     <file href="Pacote07_M1_Empreed/Unid_III_Avaliacao/aval.swf"></file>
     <file href="Pacote07_M1_Empreed/Unid_III_Avaliacao/APIWrapper.js"></file>
     <file href="Pacote07_M1_Empreed/Unid_III_Avaliacao/ieupdate.js"></file>
   </resource>

  <!-- OUTROS -->

   <resource identifier="assets" type="webcontent" adlcp:scormType="asset">
     <file href="scripts/APIWrapper.js" />
     <file href="scripts/SCOFunctions.js" />
   </resource>
 </resources>


 <imsss:sequencingCollection>
  <imsss:sequencing ID="sequencia_principal">

   <!-- This course doesn't rollup a score -->
   <imsss:rollupRules objectiveMeasureWeight="1"></imsss:rollupRules>

   <!-- Set these values to prevent content from accidently being auto-completed/satisfied-->
   <imsss:deliveryControls completionSetByContent="true" objectiveSetByContent="true"/>

  </imsss:sequencing>
 </imsss:sequencingCollection>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

What sequencing strategy are you trying to implement? Can you be a bit more specific about the problem you are seeing? It looks like you are trying to modify the [golf sequencing examples](http://www.scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/golf-examples/) I published. Would be happy to answer any questions you have.

Mike